Displaying correct upload progress
I am using XMLHttpRequest to POST 400-500k files to relatively slow ESP32-based server. The upload takes several minutes. The xhr.onreadystatechange event with readyState 4 fires at the end as expected. However xhr.upload.onprogress event that updates progress bar fires almost immediately with 100% complete.
I suspect some buffer in the many layers between the browser and the application's HTTP handler absorbs entire file, making it look like it has been transmitted already.

Question 1: Is there anything I can do on a browser side to get real time progress of data being saved in the ESP FATFS?

Question 2: I probably can use SSE from different XMLHttpRequest that would receive number of bytes already written and update progress bar. This requires additional HTTP handler and asynchronous worker thread on a server. Is there something simpler I can do?


The code here is very close to what I am doing and apparently it works for the author. Could be because the files are much bigger and server faster.

i dont have much expirience with the actual code but I do know how it works. basically a post request will send back a data complete as soon as its done. what you could do is send a request for progress percentage very few seconds and wait for a response back. when you get that response update it in the HTML. I'm new to this website so sorry if I'm not much of a help. if its a buffer that absorbs the file. you could also send it byte by byte and have a system autorun on the server to compile it all together in the end and make it one file. otherwise I don't know how to help. like I said I'm new so sorry if I'm no help. i just want to try if I can :(

In order to send something back to the browser I have to send HTTP response headers first. This means that I will not be able to report an error later if something goes wrong. Or at least this is my understanding of how HTTP response works.

yeah that sounds about right. do you host your own server or host it through somebody else?

I am writing both server and client code. The server is tiny ESP32 Wi-Fi module installed on the device for wireless configuration and diagnostic.
